# How to read out values that determine the colors from an exisiting conditional format of the 'Color Scale' Type

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to read out the values that determine the colors from an exisiting conditional format that is of the `ColorScale` Type?

I understand how to apply a conditional formatting to a range via VBA code. 
What i have not been able to find on the net, nor able to get any useful info from the macro recorder, is how to read out an existing conditional format so that it returns the exact values used in the color scale.

All that MS provides for documentation is that you can modify a FormatCondition [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition.modify), but not how to read it out.

My ultimate aim is to write code that will automatically consolidate duplicate conditional formatting ranges, but without being able to get exact values for all CF, i can't compare if two CFs are identical.

Comment: @newguy Nope. This is not a duplicate of that. I understand how to get the background color. I'm asking about how to get the underlying values that determine what color is used.

Comment: You mean the conditions or rules used in a conditional format?

Comment: Yes. I mean the conditions and rules used. Especially for the ColorScale type of CF (Type=3)

Comment: I updated the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub f()

Dim o As ColorScale

Set o = Range("a1").FormatConditions(1)

Debug.Print o.ColorScaleCriteria(1).Value, o.ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value, o.ColorScaleCriteria(3).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: This will not give you the Min or Max values of a Color Scale! It will return a formula to you if one was used.

Comment: No, but doing a bit of work yourself!!!, would avail `f.colorscalecriteria` and you can look through each of those `value` s

Comment: Thanks! For the record: i did infact try various methods of trying to find exactely that and was even on the MSDN document page for that property, but somehow missed that this was the way to read out the property.